# Set div content to value of textarea

Tags: jquery, textarea

I'm setting up a submit form like this (PHP echo):

```
<form id="editForm">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="' . $name . '">
    <input type="text" id="date" name="date" value="' . $date . '">
    <div id="edittoolbox">&nbsp</div>
    <textarea id="content" name="content">' . $content . '</textarea>
</form>
```

I'm then using this jQuery to setup the 'preview' form (similar to posting/answering question on Stack Overflow where you have the top form for writing your post and the preview underneath it):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".articleTitle").html($("#name").val());
    $(".articleDate").html($("#date").val());
    $(".articleContent").html($("#content").val());
});
```

It works for setting the first two divs (`articleTitle` and `articleDate`), but I can't seem to set the html of `articleContent`, likely because `#content` is a textarea.

I've tried with `.val()`, `.text()` and `.html()`. It should be noted that the textarea contains HTML, not 'just' text.

Comment: @RobertRozas Thanks I just did, actually it wasn't there first I tried it to see if it would change anything. I still get the same problem without setting that attribute. I should note that the $content is HTML, not just pure text. Maybe that plays a role?

Comment: I set up a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/2V6Sz/

Comment: ***I can't seem to set the html of articleContent*** what exactly does this mean? the set content is not what you want? such as if the content is `<b>something</b>`, you want it to show exactly `<b>something</b>` not the styled text **something**? If so you should use `$(".articleContent").text()` instead of `.html()`

Comment: @KingKing The single div of class .articleContent on this page is empty by default. On page load I want to use some jQuery to make the content of .articleContent exactly equal to #content, so I guess it's .html() I want then. But despite the working fiddles, you can see from my page's link in my post that it's not working on my end. My guess is that's because there's html and not just pure text in my textarea

Comment: @Juicy have you tried using `$(".articleContent").text($("#content").val())` instead? Note that it is ***.text*** not ***.html***

Comment: @KingKing Yes, I tried .text, .val and .html, all three give me the result you can see in the page I've linked in the post. That is, nothing

Comment: @Juicy in fact the `.articleContent` has this style `display:none` which hides all the content. So just remove that line. If you can't change the CSS, then just use the `.show()` method to show the `.articleContent`

Comment: @KingKing Wow... don't you just hate when these things happen? Thank you and sorry to have wasted your time :) Think I could've gone all night tracking this bugger down